# How to import newly added fields into an AppFlow with an API created flow

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-appflow

There is an option: *Import Newly Added Fields Automatically* when creating/editing an AppFlow.

I want to create a new Flow using the Java SDK that sets this value to true.

The following code is part of a larger request that creates a new Flow. This section is used to map all available fields. However there is still an additional setting required to map new fields also.

```
List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    tasks.add(Task.builder()
            .taskType(TaskType.MAP_ALL)
            .sourceFields()
            .connectorOperator(
                    ConnectorOperator.builder()
                            .salesforce(NO_OP)
                            .build()
            )
            .build());
```